# infinite sum of $(x+\frac{1}{n})^n$

Tags: real-analysis

$f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb R$ by $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(x+\frac{1}{k})^k$. Is this function continuously differentiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ f_n(x)=(x+\frac{1}{n})^{n},x\in(-1,1),n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $.

The series of functions $ \sum f_n $ simply converges on $ (-1,1) $ and the functions $ f_n $ are continuously differentiable on $ (-1,1) $ and
  $$ \forall x\in(-1,1),f'_n(x)=n\left( x+\frac{1}{n}\right) ^{n-1} $$
  More over the series of functions $ \sum f'_n $ uniformly converges on each segment of $ (-1,1) $ (because for $ c\in(0,1)$, we have  $ \forall x\in[-c,c],|f'_n(x)|\leq n\left( c+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1} $ and the series $ \sum_{n\geq1} n(c+\frac{1}{n})^{n-1} $ converge).

Hence $ f $ is continuously differentiable on $ (-1,1) $ and $$ \forall x\in(-1,1),f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} n\left( x+\frac{1}{n}\right) ^{n-1} $$

Comment: I have tried this. But since $\sum f_n'$ is not uniformly convergent on (-1,1). we cannot directly claim $f$ is continuously differentiable and $f'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  f_n'$ (right?, or there is a stronger result i do not know)

Comment: To demonstrate that the sum of a series of continuously differentiable functions is continuously differentiable over an interval $ I $, it suffices to show that the series of derivatives converges uniformly on any segment included in $ I $

Comment: got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you meant to use $k$ instead of $n$, so $$f( x) =\sum ^{\infty }_{k=1}\left( x+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k}.$$
And sure it is: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n} f}{\mathrm{d} x^{n}} =\sum ^{\infty }_{k=n}\frac{k!}{( k-n) !}\left( x+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k-n}.$$
This resembles some sort of logarithm Taylor series, so I'd assume that if its some sort of Taylor series that it doesn't converge to all the desired values of $f$ for $x$ values outside $(-1,1)$, but you can certainly differentiate this infinite sum as much as you want.

Comment: Why is it? Why we can differentiate it like this while it is not a power series? in my understanding power series should be in the form $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx^k$

Comment: You can do a binomial expansion on each one of the terms and, assuming the series is absolutely convergent (proof needed) rearrange the terms to group together all the constants, $x$s, $x^2$s, $x^3$s, etc.